# Concatenate CSS variables (to add opacity to hex values)

Tags: css

In CSS you can use 8 character hex codes to denote color and opacity, e.g. `#b71c1c64` = `#b71c1c` + `64`.

I have all my site's colours as variables like so:

```css
:root {
  --color-red-50: #ffebee;
  //...
  --color-red-900: #b71c1c;
}
```

There are cases where I need to use `rgba()` - like `box-shadow`

```css
input {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

I cannot use a hex code inside an `rgba()` function, so I'd like to be able to concatenate a variable with a string (or another variable) like so:

```css
:host {
  --opacity-0: 0;
  // ...
  --opacity-100: 64;
}

input {
  box-shadow: inset 
    0 1px 1px 
      var(--color-blue-400) + var(--opacity-75),
    0 0 8px
      var(--color-blue-400) + var(--opacity-60);
}
```

I have tried:

```css
foo {
  prop: var(--color-blue-400)var(--opacity-75);
  prop: var(--color-blue-400) + var(--opacity-75);
  prop: var(--color-blue-400) & var(--opacity-75);
  prop: calc(ar(--color-blue-400) + var(--opacity-75));
  prop: calc(ar(--color-blue-400) & var(--opacity-75));
  prop: calc(ar(--color-blue-400), var(--opacity-75));

  prop: color-mix(in srgb, var(--color-blue-400) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0))
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

It's not a string concatenation, but this does solve my specific issue:

```css
--color-blue-400: #42a5f5;

box-shadow: inset
  0 1px 1px 
    color-mix(in srgb, var(--color-blue-400) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,0)),
  0 0 8px 
    color-mix(in srgb, var(--color-blue-400) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,0));
```